# Если в массиве есть число совпадающее с заданным то удалить, если нет то добавить в массив

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

У меня в БД есть такая схема:

```
const randomSchema = new Schema({
    elem1: {
        type: String
        , required: true
    }
    , elem2: {
        type: [Number]
        , default: []
        , required: true

    }
, })
```

Лишнее я убрал за ненадобностью

Как мы видим - в поле `elem2` у нас лежит массив чисел.

Что мне нужно сделать:

Допустим, что у меня есть число 8855.

Мне нужно проверить есть ли такое число среди элементов данного массива и если оно есть то удалить, а если нету то добавить в массив.

Код не прикрепил, потому что мне не удалось написать что-то хоть немного приближенное к данному функционалу.

Comment: Достаете из БД массив, проверяете на наличие числа и, в зависимости от результата,  делаете нужное действие. Я бы делал так

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте $addToSet. Пример:

```
{ _id: 1, letters: ["a", "b"] }
```

---

```
db.test.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: {letters: "c" } }
)
```

---

```
{ _id: 1, letters: [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

Ссылка на доку - [ссылка](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

Comment: А если "с" уже есть в массиве,  "с" будет удалено?

Comment: Сорри, пропустил про "удалить элемент если существует". Действительно наверное верным решением будет достать документ -> сделать фильтр для массива -> ну и проапдейтить документ с нужным уже массивом.